# How to use files within salt directory for cmd.run?

Tags: salt-stack, concourse

I want to run a command (`cmd.run`) which uses files within the salt directory, for example:

```
fly_set_{{ pipeline }}:
  cmd.run:
    - name: |
        fly -t ci set-pipeline -p {{ pipeline }} -c pipeline.yml -l credentials.yml
    - require:
      - cmd: fly_login_{{name}}
        - file: /etc/concourse/teams/builds/{{ pipeline }}/pipeline.yml
        - file: /etc/concourse/teams/builds/{{ pipeline }}/credentials.yml
```

Is this the correct approach or do I need to do this first?

```
file:
  managed:
    - source: salt://concourse/teams/builds/{{ pipeline }}/pipeline.yml
```

Comment: Clarify where you want to execute cmd.run , in the salt-server ? or salt-minion?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what are you trying to achieve, but if your command is depending on multiple files the right way to do this would be:

```
/etc/concourse/teams/builds/{{ pipeline }}/pipeline.yml:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://concourse/teams/builds/{{ pipeline }}/pipeline.yml

/etc/concourse/teams/builds/{{ pipeline }}/credentials.yml:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://concourse/teams/builds/{{ pipeline }}/credentials.yml

fly_set_{{ pipeline }}:
  cmd.run:
    - name: |
        fly -t ci set-pipeline -p {{ pipeline }} -c pipeline.yml -l credentials.yml
    - require:
      - file: /etc/concourse/teams/builds/{{ pipeline }}/pipeline.yml
      - file: /etc/concourse/teams/builds/{{ pipeline }}/credentials.yml
```

First two `file.managed` directive will ensure that both files are present on the minion. The `require` directive in `cmd.run` will make sure that files are present on the minion *before* the execution of the command.